# "in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'"

Tags: html, browser, web

My website is www.devoncarlson.me . When the "About Me" link is pressed, I would like the user to be redirected to a random youtube video from a list. I've purchased my domain from Hover, and it's being hosted for free through github. When the "About Me" link is pressed I get the error "in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'" in my console. How can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The sentence begins with "in a frame because"...!? And in a nutshell: Youtube.com doesn't like to be embedded in frames.